# Getting 0x80070005 - JavaScript runtime error: Access is denied while loading the MS word add-in

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ms-word, ms-office, office-js, word-addins

When i start my add-in first it shows below error:

> 0x80070005 - JavaScript runtime error: Access is denied.

and Highlighted the

> var t=window.localStorage

code in js file.
Add-in working after click on continue button. Please advice me how i can handle this error while running the word add-in using visual studio 2015.

I have used word javascript api and when i tried to use local storage, add-in stopped working due to local storage issue.

Page Header:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <title>Testing</title>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.0.custom/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/FabricUI/MessageBanner.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

   <script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/Office/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.0.custom/jquery-ui.min.css" />
    <link href="Home.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="DesignElements.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/2.2.0/fabric.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/2.2.0/fabric.components.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/2.2.0/fabric.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/2.2.0/fabric.components.css">

    <!--During development turn off caching-->
  <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
  <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
  <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
  <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
  <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
</head>
```

Thanks.

Comment: What version of Word are you using?  I'm assuming Office 2013 or 2016 for Windows desktop?  Could you post a version number?

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky : Yes, office 2016 for windows desktop.

Comment: Are you using the local  Office.js script? or are you using the CDN?

Comment: @EasyE I am using script from CDN, URL: https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js

Comment: can you post the head of your HTML home page ? I am thinking you are calling something out of place.

Comment: @EasyE : i have added the page head in question, please check.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got my head, I had a funky issue with fabric so I call it last.  I would try to organize, it really seems like you are calling something out of sync

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
<title>MY Example</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/lib/1.0.12/js/adal.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

<script src="MessageBanner.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<link href="Home.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="Home.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.2/moment.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="GeneralContent/GeneralContent.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Graphics/Graphics.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/js/kendo.all.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/fabric-core/4.0.0/fabric.min.css">

<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```